# Regex preg_match with str_replace

Tags: php, regex, file

I want to replace a regex by a string. So I use the fonction str_replace and preg_match like that :

```
str_replace (preg_match('<user-id type="integer">[0-9]{1,10}<\/user-id>', $file), 'hello', $file)
```

With that I have an error "preg_match(): Unknown modifier '[' " but I don't why I have that because the regex is right, I test it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: you need a delimiter in the `preg_match` function - `preg_match('@<user-id type="integer">[0-9]{1,10}<\/user-id>@'` ?

Comment: @RamRaider: Transfer this to an answer. There are a couple of duplicates though :)

Comment: I am closing most of regex delimiter questions as dupes since they are 1) evident, 2) numerous, 3) require very little effort to check in the documentation. PHP regexes are discussed thoroughly in the SO regex tag posts.

Comment: I post it because I test a lot of combinations and even the answer of @RamRaider doesn't Work for me

Comment: Issue resolved, I didn't escape the "